# JAVA_HOME variable is Set but not working 20.04 - PLEASE HELP.!

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have installed:

```
Openjdk "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-posto-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1 )
OpenJDK 64-bIT sERVER vm (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have already Set the `JAVA_HOME` environment Variable both for the user (me) and Root, (correctly I think.!) editing the `/etc/environment`.
And I need to install Siemens NX-12 in my computer - lENOVO P72, 64 Bit with Xeon processor with Ubuntu-MATE 20.04.
I've mounted the .ISO  and when I try to start the installation the message that I got is:

```
No Java virtual Machine could be found from your PATH enfironment variable.
You Must install a VM prior to running this program.
```

I really don't know what else to do !!  Can anybody, Please give me some solution ?
All the instructions that I've found are not updated to version 20.04.

For the Prior version ( 18.04 ) I've succeeded in setting the JAVA_HOME and got the NX-12 installed, but not for the 20.04.

Comment: What is the output of `type -a java`?

Comment: run `. /etc/environment` in your terminal

Comment: From where you have installed the Java version with *posto-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1* suffix? Also please show the output of `update-java-alternatives -l` and `dpkg -l | grep -i java` .

Comment: Hi Folks !  Thank you very much for your Attention and help !
When I "type":   type - a java       it returns:   
java is   /usr/bin/java
java is   /bin/java
And the Output of the: "update-java-alternatives -l "    it  returns:

Comment: Hi Folks !  Thank you very much for your Attention and help !
When I "type":   type - a java       it returns:   
java is   /usr/bin/java
java is   /bin/java
And the Output of the: "update-java-alternatives -l "    it  returns:
awk: cannot open /usr/lib/jvm/*.jinfo (no such file or directrory)
jdk-14.0.1                                 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-14.0.1

So  I don't know if it's right or not,  but  I still keep getting the same message when I try to install NX-12  License Servrer in order to install  NX-12 !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is OpenJDK, You need to download Oracal JDK 8 from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html
and change the primary to Oracle JDK as here https://www.fosstechnix.com/install-oracle-java-8-on-ubuntu-20-04/ . Please let me know if you succeeded with the installations.